# Apache Superset connection with MS SQL Server not working

Tags: python, sql-server, docker, apache-superset

I have installed Apache superset locally using docker-compose using  `docker-compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml up` and now when i try to connect it to ms server using connection string it doesnot work either with pyodbc or mssql, also i tested the connection string using python script and it works proprly but not in superset
the connection string is `mssql+pyodbc://UserName:password@host:port/TestSchema`

Comment: "Doesn't work" ... how? Do you get an error message? Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70615145/edit) your question to include the full and complete error message - as text, not screen shot(s).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning pymssql is deprecated, its also the same regarding DB name also tried adding the  ``` ?Encrypt=<yes|no>``` still not working

Comment: the thing is maybe pyodbc isnot installed with the docker-compose way of installing, but how do i add it to it, should i get into  a container of them and install it or what